# How to return one single specific element by using map function(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, dictionary

I am trying to return one element from array using map function and instead one single element after map, I have one element that displays as many times as there are elements in the array.

```
{this.state.cities.map(() =>
          this.state.cities[0].value > 10 ? (
            <p style={{ color: "red" }}>
              {this.state.cities[0].name} - {this.state.cities[0].value}
            </p>
          ) : (
            <p>
              {" "}
              {this.state.cities[0].name} - {this.state.cities[0].value}
            </p>
          )
        )}
```

Comment: you want a city which has a `value` greater than 10?, If yes, use `[].find` method and display it

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe now is more clear. I would be very grateful for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the map argument to see which value object has you criteria:

In other words, if the value is > 10 it will display the paragraph in red otherwise just display the rest of the paragraphs

```
{this.state.cities.map((city) =>
          city.value > 10 ? (
            <p style={{ color: "red" }}>
              {city.name} - {city.value}
            </p>
          ) : (
            <p>
              {" "}
              {city.name} - {city.value}
            </p>
          )
        )}
```